# Multiple Lamp indicators and LED driving using TPL7407LA simultaneously

Tags: driver, darlington

I am using [TPL7407LA](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407la.pdf) for driver circuit, it will be getting inputs from [pic18f67k40](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/PIC18(L)F67K40%20Data%20Sheet%2040001841D.pdf) and driving multiple Lamp indicators(24v) and multiple LED indicators(12v).
My question is : Is it possible to control multiple LEds and lamp indicators simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to drive multiple lamps and LEDs. 
The maximum supply we can provide is 30 V as per below table. The minimum voltage needed to signal a logic high is 1.5 V which I believe your PIC microcontroller will definitely provide. The driver is 1.8 V to 5V logic signal compatible.
[image]

Care also about the current you can sink via this Low side driver. Per channel it allows upto 500 mA but it depends on the package and also on number of **simultaneously** switched loads.

[image].

> At any input voltage the output drivers is going to be driven at its
>   maximum when Vcom is greater than or equal to 6.5 V."
>
> So does it mean if i supply Vcom pin greater than 6.5v it will be able
>   to drive connected loads which are of 12v and 24v respectively ?

Yes. For any logical input voltage level, be it 1.8 Vor 3.3V or 5 V for example, the loads will be driven with complete supplied voltage (when higher than 6.5 V). Hence, the lamp indicator will be definitely drive with complete applied voltage of 24V.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Comment: LEDs and Lamp indicators which i am using require very less current(20mA). On page number 12 of the datasheet it is mentioned that "At any input voltage the output drivers is going to be driven at its maximum when Vcom is greater than or equal to 6.5 V." So does it mean if i supply Vcom pin greater than 6.5v it will be able to drive connected loads which are of 12v and 24v respectively ?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: in figure 3 of the datasheet, the graph is Output current Vs Duty Cycle. The duty cycle of what? switching of output channels?

Comment: if duty cycle is 100%, the load is continuously on. If the duty cycle is 50%, the load is 50% of the time ON and 50% of the time OFF. Blinking a LED (Duty cycle 50%) instead of keeping it on continuously (Duty Cycle 100%)